# Rejoin split file on server using PHP

Tags: php

I am wondering if it is possible to do the following:

- Split a file on the local computer to several pieces so I can upload
  them on to the FTP server (avoiding this way the file size limit)
- Upload all pieces to my web server
- Using a PHP script rejoin them together into one file

I know about HJSplit but it is for the other way around situation (to split on server and then rejoin on local computer)

Does anyone know about any possible solution?

Comment: It's possible, but if you're trying to upload a file larger than what the hosting allows you, you're probably breaking their TOS. (if not, consider asking them to increase the limit).

Comment: Ive done this in the past, tho using a server(local) to server approach, with curl multi its also very fast tx

Comment: Have you considered the FileReader API? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/FileReader

Comment: RE Truth: I have this free account with limit of 5mb per file and I have just one single file out of hundreds which is about 7mb so I needed a way to push it in somehow. I doubt they will increase me a limit as that's what the paid account is for so I will take a risk and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This site claims to have some packages for split and then join.](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2502-PHP-Split-files-in-pieces-that-can-be-gathered-later.html) 
However I am not sure if they work.(Not Tried)

Comment: This is it! it works flawlessly and does exactly what I need it to do, thank you very much Kislay (thanks to you all for the quick reply it all is useful)

Answer (score -1):

This could make splitting part:

```
    <html>
<body>
  <label >
  <div align="right" >
  </div>
</label>
<form method="POST" action="">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Here you Files to spilited</td>
            <td>Value</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> For spilt Zip File to  paste Its Url</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="zipurl" /></td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Spilt to Valume Size:  part</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="spitsize" value="50"/></td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Mega bite (1 On/ 0 off) </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="megabyte" value="1"/></td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Kilo Byte (1 On/ 0 off)</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="kilobyte" value="0"/></td>

        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" name="ssurlsubmit" value="submit" />
    </form>



</body>
<?php 
$mypath = getcwd();
  $mypath = preg_replace('/\\\\/', '/', $mypath);

$targetfolder = $mypath.'/tmp';
echo 'targetfolder is:   '.$targetfolder.'<br />';
    if (!is_dir("$mypath/tmp")) {
mkdir("$mypath/tmp");
echo 'Dir'.$targetfolder.'created'.'<br />';

} 

$targetfolder = $mypath.'/tmp'.'<br />';

/*
if(!file_exists($targetfolder)) {
    if(mkdir($targetfolder)) {
        echo "Created target folder $targetfolder".br();
    }
    else{
    echo '$targetfolder can not be created'.br();
}
}else
{
echo $targetfolder.'$targetfolder exist '.br();
}
*/
?>
</html>

<?php
/*
 --------------------------------------------------
 filesplit.php HJSplit compatiple PHP file splitter
 --------------------------------------------------

 File name: 
    filesplit.php                
 Author: 
    Umit Tirpan 2007-03-22          
    Umit Tirpan 2008-03-12 [remote file support added]         
 Author's Website: 
    http://forum.iyinet.com/

 Description:
    This PHP script, splits the files into smaller pieces in binary.
    It is compatiple with HJSplit, so you can re-join splitted files using HJSplit's Join utility.
    It can split a file up to 999 pieces.

 What is the use, why will I use this?
    Some webmasters do not have shell access to their websites. This prevents them splitting big files, ie. MySQL backups, into smaller files. Splitting a 200Mb file into 10 x 20Mb file may be easy on webmaster to download in pieces. 

 How to run:
    Make sure your webserver has write permission on the target folder.
    Edit variables. 
    Upload (ftp) this file to your webserver or run on your PC.
    For security reason, filename is hardcoded. You can modify code to accept $_GET['filename']

 Run with your favorite browser.
    http://www.<your-web-site>.com/filesplit.php
 Or run on shell (ie. ssh)
    php filesplit.php

 It is Ok to share and modify this code and use in/with your applications. No restrictions.

 */




// ---------------------------
// Edit variables (3 variables)
// ---------------------------

// File to split, is its not in the same folder with filesplit.php, full path is required.

global $ssurl,$filename;
if (isset($_POST['zipurl'])) {
$url=$_POST['zipurl'];
$filename=$_POST['zipurl'];
echo "URL:".$url.'<br />';
}

//  $filename = "http://www.iyinet.com/my-big-file.zip"; 

// Target folder. Splitted files will be stored here. Original file never gets touched.
// Do not append slash! Make sure webserver has write permission on this folder.
$mypath = getcwd();
  $mypath = preg_replace('/\\\\/', '/', $mypath);

$targetfolder = $mypath.'/tmp';
echo 'targetfolder is:   '.$targetfolder.'<br />';
    if (!is_dir("$mypath/tmp")) {
mkdir("$mypath/tmp");
echo 'Dir'.$targetfolder.'created'.'<br />';

} 

$targetfolder = $mypath.'/tmp';

// File size in Mb per piece/split. 
// For a 200Mb file if piecesize=10 it will create twenty 10Mb files
$piecesize = 50; // splitted file size in MB
if (isset($_POST['spitsize'])) {
$piecesize=$_POST['spitsize'];

}

//$piecesize = 10; // splitted file size in MB



// ---------------------------
// Do NOT edit this section
// ---------------------------

$buffer = 1024;
if (isset($_POST['megabyte'])and $_POST['megabyte']=='1') {
//$piece=$_POST['megabyte'];
$piece = 1048576*$piecesize;

}
if (isset($_POST['kilobyte']) and $_POST['kilobyte']==1) {
//$piece=$_POST['kilobyte'];
$piece = 1024*$piecesize;

}
//$piece = 1048576*$piecesize;
$current = 0;
$splitnum = 1;

if(!file_exists($targetfolder)) {
    if(mkdir($targetfolder)) {
        echo "Created target folder $targetfolder".br();
    }
    echo '$targetfolder folder exist'.br();
}

if(!$handle = fopen($filename, "rb")) {
    die("Unable to open $filename for read! Make sure you edited filesplit.php correctly!".br());
}

$base_filename = basename($filename);
/*
$ss=substr($base_filename,-4);
echo substr($base_filename,-4).'<br />';
if ($ss=='.zip') 
 { 
 $end='.zip';

 $base_filename= removeFromEnd($base_filename, '.zip');
 }
 */
$piece_name = $targetfolder.'/'.$base_filename.'.'.str_pad($splitnum, 3, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT). $end;
if(!$fw = fopen($piece_name,"w")) {
    die("Unable to open $piece_name for write. Make sure target folder is writeable.".br());
}
echo "Splitting $base_filename into $piecesize Mb files ".br()."(last piece may be smaller in size)".br();
echo "Writing $piece_name...".br();
while (!feof($handle) and $splitnum < 999) {
    if($current < $piece) {
        if($content = fread($handle, $buffer)) {
            if(fwrite($fw, $content)) {
                $current += $buffer;
            } else {
                die("filesplit.php is unable to write to target folder. Target folder may not have write permission! Try chmod +w target_folder".br());
            }
        }
    } else {
        fclose($fw);
        $current = 0;
        $splitnum++;
        $piece_name = $targetfolder.'/'.$base_filename.'.'.str_pad($splitnum, 3, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
        echo "Writing $piece_name...".br();
        $fw = fopen($piece_name,"w");
    }
}
fclose($fw);
fclose($handle);
echo "Done! ".br();
exit;

function br() {
    return (!empty($_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE']))?'<br>':"\n";
}
function removeFromEnd($string, $stringToRemove) {
     $stringToRemoveLen = strlen($stringToRemove);
     $stringLen = strlen($string);

     $pos = $stringLen - $stringToRemoveLen;    

     $out = substr($string, 0, $pos);

     return $out;
 }
?>
```

you could test it via :

http://restss2.frogcp.com/tmp/filesplit%2520%282%29.php